# find the most frequent number in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I've recently started learning C and I ran into this small test.

> Make a code which reads 10 numbers from a user.
>
> Print the Largest & Smallest entered values then print the most frequent number.

Making everything was simple for me but the most-frequent number is driving me crazy, I've searched for awhile and couldn't find any clear answers.

The code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int hi[10], i=0, largest, smallest;
    while(i<10)
    {
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &hi[i]);
        i++;
    }
    smallest = hi[0];
    largest = hi[0];
    printf("Entered Numbers: ");
    while(i!=0)
    {
        if(hi[10-i] < smallest) { smallest = hi[10-i]; }
        if(hi[10-i] > largest) { largest = hi[10-i]; }
        printf("%d | ", hi[10-i]);
        i--;
    }

    printf("\nLargest number is = %d || Smallest number is = %d", largest, smallest);
    return 0;
}
```

The only idea I thought of was:

- Making another array.
- Getting value of [i] in the original array.
- Compare [i] with rest of values of original array (if they are equal or not).
- Increment the value of the other array if they are equal.
- Check largest value in the other array and that should be most frequent number.
- Now, I know the order of most frequent element and how many times that element was entered.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo: Well, yes, that seems to be the solution which the OP has already figured out. Which seems sensible enough to me.

Comment: Look at the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566265/frequency-of-numbers-in-a-1d-array and edit it to meet your needs.

Comment: Sort the array.  Then enumerate the items in the array from hi[0]..h[9] in a for-loop.  Then use extra variables to keep track of the duplicate count.

Comment: @sudo_coffee That's exactly what I needed! modified it a bit and that worked.
doynax, ayy so I guess my idea weren't that bad. I was basically afraid of messing up somewhere in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a hashmap would be more efficient. There you can use the input number as key and set the value to 1. When a new number was given by the user, you just have to check wether the new number is already in the map. If so, you set the value to two, otherwise you add the new number with the value 1.

Comment: It seems to me that such a scheme would add rather a lot of complexity and limited benefit for 10 elements. Still, sensible enough for larger problem sets

Comment: Yes, thats totally correct. But I think this not a "real world problem". Its just to learn programming. And there a hint to a hashmap is good to learn something about this data structure ;)

Comment: hashmap is something I've never heard of or met before.
Learning new stuff is also important for me as I move forward, I will check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing on what Markus said, a hash map really is ideal for a universal solution so you can keep the asymptotic time down, but since you're only doing an array of 10, using a 2D array to store the frequency will work just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int hi[10][2], i=0,j=0,largest, smallest;

    while(i<10)
    {
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &hi[i][0]);
        i++;
    }
    smallest = hi[0][0];
    largest = hi[0][0];
    printf("Entered Numbers: ");
    while(i!=0)
    {
        hi[10-i][1] = 0;
        if(hi[10-i][0] < smallest) { smallest = hi[10-i][0]; }
        if(hi[10-i][0] > largest) { largest = hi[10-i][0]; }
        printf("%d | ", hi[10-i][0]);
        i--;
    }
    int most_freq = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            if(hi[i][0] == hi[j][0]){
                hi[i][1]++;
                if (hi[i][1] > most_freq){
                    most_freq = hi[i][0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nLargest number is = %d || Smallest number is = %d", largest, smallest);
    printf("\nMost frequent is = %d\n", most_freq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code _as formatted text_ instead.

Comment: Will do in the future, my apologies.

Comment: You don't really need a 2-D array here. It would be clearer to use 2 arrays - so using `hi[i]` and `count[i]` instead of `hi[i][0]` and `hi[i][1]`.