# c# Roll Dice simulation to return how many times every side landed

Tags: c#, arrays, dice

My first post on here! I started learning how to program a couple of days ago and have picked up a rolling dice project. I think I have done the main part of it but my problem comes from:

Printing how many times each side came up (maybe store them in an array)?
Bonus: Print out the percentage of times each side appeared (rounded up to 2 decimals)

Keep in mind the times and sides are user input so could be e.g. 50 times x 35 sides.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Dice_roll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
            {
                Random randomRoll = new Random();
                lock (randomRoll)
                {
                    return randomRoll.Next(min, max);
                }
            }

            int sides, rollTimes, i;
            i = 0;
            bool boolCheckSides = false;
            bool boolCheckRolls = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to a little dice rolling program.\n Select how many sides you want the dice to have: \n");
            do
            {
                boolCheckSides = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out sides);
                if (boolCheckSides == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number.. \n");
                }
            } while (boolCheckSides == false);

            Console.WriteLine("Now select how many times you want it to roll: \n");
            do
            {
                boolCheckRolls = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rollTimes);
                if (boolCheckRolls == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number.. \n");
                }
            } while (boolCheckRolls == false);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rolling... " + getRandomNumber(1, sides));
                i = i + 1;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            } while (i < rollTimes);



            int[] arr = new int[rollTimes];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if my code is messy or something, I'm still very beginner.

Comment: Storing them in an array sounds like a very good idea, I would advise going with trying that (and comming back here if you can't get it to work). That said a few comments. Is the `Thread.Sleep` part of the assignment or was that your solution to the random generator seemingly generating the same random nummer after each other? The sleep will prevent people being able to simulate a lot of rolls. Thing is you should not create a new `Random` gor each roll, just create it once and then use it.

Comment: I did the `Thread.Sleep` to simulate the program "thinking" and then rolling not just spamming the screen full. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by preventing them simulate rolls.. They input sides and rolls in the beginning and then I have a method which keeps rolling the `Random` while `int i < rollTimes` I also made a little array in the bottom to check if I'm storing the data properly and it is doing it but the problem is how do I then print out how many times each numbers that got rolled were duplicate.

Comment: I meant that if someone wants to simulate a million rolls it would take a very long time for your program to finish, since every roll takes half a second. As for the array, create it before you start rolling, and create it to be of size the amount of sides you're rolling. Then every roll increase the value of the side you rolled in the array by 1 (so you count for every side how many times it rolled). Keep in mind though that arrays are 0-indexed. Meaning the count for how many 1s you rolled will be at index 0 in the array

Comment: `Random randomRoll = new Random();` is seeded by timestamp. It's better to just initialize it once. You can make it static or a member field.

Comment: `randomRoll.Next(min, max);`  care, the min value is inclusive, but max value is exclusive

Comment: @Knoop Ah yes I understand now! You are right but I guess I tried to make it like a little fun program, never assumed I'll pick a roll over 100.. In your context would remove that `Thread.Sleep`. I will read your other explanation a couple of times and try that, thank you!

Comment: @Stefan Kinda confused by what you said due to my limited knowledge.. I will google some more and try to understand it.

Comment: It's a minor detail, but to sum it; it's best not to call `new Random()` from within a loop. You might have a chance you'll get duplicate values. You might be able to spot it if you remove the Thread.Sleep

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for clarifying.. How would I go about it in this scenario then? I first tried doing something like `Console.WriteLine(rollTimes * getRandomNumber(1, sides));` but that didn't quite work out as planned haha.

Comment: @Frenchy Apologize for my incompetence but I do not know what inclusive/exclusive means and how it affects the way this statement works..

Comment: exclusive means the value will be never in range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I assume that your code is not complete yet, so I will just share some opinions of mine.

1- You are adding a method getRandomNumber inside your main function. This method won't compile and should be moved outside the scope of main function. The scope of main function is any code between the curly brackets "{}" shown in the code below

```
static void main(string[] args){}
```

just a small side note, try to use Uppercase letters for naming methods in C#, except the main function as that's a naming convention ;-)

2- You did a great job in declaring the variables you need (boolCheckSides, boolCheckRolls, i) before you start assigning them values. However, you also need to declare the Array before using it not after, so your code should look something like this

```
//Declare the Array
int[] arr = new int[rollTimes];

do
{
    int temp = getRandomNumber(1, sides);
    Console.WriteLine("Rolling... " + temp);
    //Save the value acquired from this roll in the array
    arr[i] = temp;
    i = i + 1;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
} while (i < rollTimes);
```

Then you can easily play around with the array and find the frequency of any number. I would suggest you refer to this post [Count the frequency of element of an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555652/count-the-frequency-of-element-of-an-array-in-c-sharp) if you want to find the short answer, and refer to this post [Frequency of Numbers in a 1D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566265/frequency-of-numbers-in-a-1d-array) for the long answer. Just please note that the second post is using C++ language, but it is still showing the same logic though.

3- Just a small advise, please try to avoid "do...while" loops as much as possible. It needs a lot of attention when you write them as they can easily get you into infinite loop.

Comment: Very clear explanation using simple terms and statements so that I could understand it, thank you very very much! So I should name it `GetRandomNumber` instead of  `getRandomNumber` and put it in the scope of the `class Program` instead of the main method? Very straightforward on the whole array thing as well, thank you.

Comment: You are always welcome. And yes for the naming of the method and moving it to the class scope. Great job with your first code as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Dictionary, with the side (1 to X) as Key and number of time its appears .

```
class Program
{
    Dictionary<int, int> RollDice = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        :
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to a little dice rolling program.\n Select how many sides you want the dice to have: \n");
        do
        {
            boolCheckSides = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out sides);
            if (boolCheckSides == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number.. \n");
            }
        } while (boolCheckSides == false);
        //Initialize the dictionary with key and value
        for(int i = 1; i<=sides;i++)
             RollDice.Add(i, 0);

       :
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            var value = getRandomNumber(1, sides + 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Rolling... " + value);
            RollDice[i]++; 
            i = i + 1;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        } while (i < rollTimes);
```

and you could display your stats by looping over the dictionary:

```
foreach (var pair in RollDice)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DiceSide:{pair.Key} , appears: {pair.Value}, probability: {(float)pair.Value/(float)rollTimes:0.00}");
}
```